# How do I remove an element from my Array List?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java.util.scanner

So i want to ask the user if they would like to remove an element from the array list. The array list is a list of favorite colors that is read in from a file. So lets say the contents of the array list are- Red, Orange, Green, Blue. I'm wondering how I would remove an element based off user input. Would it be something like-

```
System.in.println("Which color would you like to remove")
removeColor = reader.nextString
if removeColor (//using pseudo code here) contains removeColor, remove from ArrayList
```

Am I on the right track? Heres my code so far. Thanks!

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList <String> favoriteColors = new ArrayList <String>();
        boolean repeat = true;
        while (repeat) {

            System.out.println("Enter the name of the file which contains your favorite colors ");
            String fileName = input.nextLine().trim();

            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

                String line;
                System.out.println("Here are your favorite colors according to the file:");  
                 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {    
                   System.out.println(line);   
                   favoriteColors.add((line));
                 }                                                

                 System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");
                 if (input.next().startsWith("y")) {
                     System.out.println("Enter : ");
                     favoriteColors.add(input.next());
                 } else {
                     System.out.println("have a nice day");
                 }
                 for (int i = 0; i < favoriteColors.size(); i++) {
                     System.out.println(favoriteColors
                 if (input.next().startsWith("y")) {
                 System.out.println("Remove a color?")
                 if (input.next().startsWith("y")) {
                 /something along the lines of the pseudo code I wrote above
```

Comment: just call remove, it will either remove the element if an equal one is in the `List` or it won´t.

Comment: Yeah you're on the right track. Take a look a the Arraylist documentation - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html , specifically the `remove` methods.

Comment: One little hint: if you're writing a program to keep a list of someone's favorite colors, you probably don't need a `favoriteMovies` variable.

Comment: @ajb it was movies originally haha forgot to change it

Comment: one more thing you want to check the element based on the user input so any restriction of the word after that you are going to check in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how the remove method in an ArrayList works:

the method remove is implemented as following:

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            if (elementData[index] == null) {
                fastRemove(index);
                return true;
            }
    } else {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
                fastRemove(index);
                return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

than means the objects that are hold by the list must be able to implement this criteria:

```
if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
```

Ergo:

if your ***favoriteColors*** class are just strings then it will work

but if they are something custom made by you, then you need to implement equals in that class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop the favoriteColors list to check for the matching string color, if found then use that index to remove the element using `favoriteColors.remove(index)`

However I recommended to use Set collections not List, like HashSet, all keys are unique and contains many useful methods in your case like add(colorString), remove(colorString) and contains(colorString) to check for existing color.

Comment: why would he need to loop over the array if he can just call `List#remove`? That method simply removes the element if it´s there or doesn´t do anything

Comment: List.remove(Object) is internally doing the same loop then remove, but remove by index is faster if you know the index .. I recommended here to use Set for better performance if the list is huge as set don't do re-index

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse through the arraylist and get the index of the element which you want,

```
int index = favoriteColors.indexOf("<the color you want to remove>")
```

Then remove that element from the arraylist,

```
    favoriteColors.remove(index);
```